# Positioning of DDL items?

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

i have a dropDownList which gets its data from a database. Now after the data has bound, i programmatically add another listItem to the ddl, like so:

```
protected void ddlEffects_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddl = dwNewItem.FindControl("ddlEffects") as DropDownList;
    ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem("","0")); //Adds an empty item so the user can select it and the item doesnt provide an effect
}
```

It all works, but the problem is that the newly added listItem appears at the bottom of the DDL. I want it to be the first item. I tried making the value 0, but its still at the bottom. Is there any way to put it at the top?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check into the ddl.Items.Insert method that will allow you to insert items at a specific location.

Like this for example:

```
        using (Entities db = new Entities())
        {
            ddlDocumentTypes.DataSource = (from q in db.zDocumentTypes where (q.Active == true) select q);
            ddlDocumentTypes.DataValueField = "Code";
            ddlDocumentTypes.DataTextField = "Description";
            ddlDocumentTypes.DataBind();
            ddlDocumentTypes.Items.Insert(0, "--Select--");
            ddlDocumentTypes.Items[0].Value = "0";
        }
```

Which using EF loads the DDL with items for the database, and then inserts at position zero a new item.